# Filepond: Load default image files

Tags: filepond

I want to use filepond as my product editor.

How to load current images that is stored on the server? So visitor can decide wheter to change the current images or add a new image.

It's like this form:
=> https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/{your_user_id}

prefill some data if it has been filled before, but shows nothing when its hasnt been filled before.

I'm mentioning this filepond:
=> https://github.com/pqina/filepond

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for? An introduction on how to set initial files: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-object/#setting-initial-files

Comment: Documentation site has been updated and setting initial files is now at https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#files

Comment: you can use poster plugin https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/plugins/file-poster/

Answer (score 0):

This is my code on how I show a default image.

```
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('#image');

        const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, options);

            pond.setOptions({
            allowImagePreview: true,
            acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'],

            server: {

                process: {
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                    },
                },
                revert: {
                    url: 'deleteTmpImage.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                        '_method': 'DELETE',
                    },
                },
                load: (uniqueFileId, load) => {
                fetch(uniqueFileId)
                    .then(res => res.blob())
                    .then(load);
                },
            },
            files: [
                    {
                        source: 'https://www.example.com/default_image.jpg',
                        options: {
                            type: 'local',
                        }
                    },
                ]
        });
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.